# Этимология и морфемный состав слова «новичок»

Tags: этимология, словообразование, морфемика, морфемный-разбор

Как произошло слово *новичок*? Какой у него морфемный состав? Связано ли оно со словом *старичок*?

Comment: Здесь так принято? Сам задал вопрос, сам на него ответил, сам себе плюсанул? Так набираются очки?

Comment: @Niemand почитать о формате «вопрос — ответ» можно, например, здесь: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слово *новичок* 'Тот, кто недавно начал заниматься чем-либо' **произошло от прилагательного *новый***. Вернее, между прилагательным *новый* и существительным *новичок* была еще одна промежуточная ступень — слово *новик* 'то же' (сравните: старый — старик — старичок).

В современном русском языке слово *новик* утратилось, поэтому суффикс *-ик*, который в нем выделялся (как сейчас выделяется в слове *стар**ик***), слился с суффиксом *-ок* в слове *старичок*. Таким образом, в слове *новичок* **корень *нов-*, суффикс *-ичок* и нулевое окончание**.

Да, у слов *старичок* и *новичок* одна и та же словообразовательная модель.